# AnnotationActionValidatorManager - Caught exception while loading file java/lang/Object-validation.xml

Tags: java, struts2, nullpointerexception

Struts version of our application is 2.3.8. Getting following exception after every post back to the server. 
Application is deployed on to WebSphere server. We don't have any validation xml in the project.

```
ERROR com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager - Caught exception while loading file java/lang/Object-validation.xml

java.lang.NullPointerException at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.loadFile(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:391) at        com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.buildClassValidatorConfigs(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:279) at 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.buildValidatorConfigs(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:371) at 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.buildValidatorConfigs(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:350) at 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.getValidators(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:102) at 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.validate(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:141) at 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.validate(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:133) at 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.validate(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:128) at 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doBeforeInvocation(ValidationInterceptor.java:222)
```

Comment: Do you use validator annotation?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug since Struts2 2.3.4 version. You can refer the [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3850). This bug has been fixed in 2.3.7 version. I would recommend you to verify that all your Struts2 libraries are properly updated and deployed with the correct version. Please try upgrading your Struts2 to higher version. The difference i see is that exception accurs with `AnnotationActionValidatorManager` in your case, where as in the bug list. it is `DefaultActionValidatorManager` on which `loadFile()` method is invoked

Comment: We have the struts 2.3.8 version , but still when i see the loadFile method code in AnnotationActionValidatorManager or DefaultActionValidatorManager class. I see this code.
As per Jira, this code is causing issue:-
***if (((checkFile) && (this.fileManager.fileNeedsReloading(fileUrl))) || (!this.validatorFileCache.containsKey(fileName))) {***

Any thoughts on this? Why this culprit code is lying in xwork-core-2.3.8.jar?

Comment: Are you sure that your classpath is clean and doesn't have any old jars. just a heads up!

Comment: Yes. we dont have any older jar in classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Struts2 always loads the validation.xml file present in xwork-version.jar. This might get this error,check it manually once.

Comment: Can you be more specific? where and Which version I should check?