# Struts 2.3.16 - DefaultActionValidatorManager.loadFile() throws NullPointerException while loading Object-validation.xml

Tags: java, configuration, struts2, nullpointerexception, struts-validation

We are upgrading struts from 2.0.11 to 2.3.16.

In our code while trying to get `DefaultActionValidatorManager.getValidators(getClass()`, null), it throws a `NullPointerException` from `DefaultActionValidatorManager.loadFile()` while it tries to load `java/lang/Object-validation.xml`.

Searching on internet I found a similar issue was reported as [WW-3850](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3850). It says the issue is fixed in xwork 2.3.7. I took a look at xwork 2.3.7 source and it has the mentioned changed (additional null check `fileUrl != null`). This check is present till xwork 2.3.14.3 and is removed from 2.3.15 onward.

Any idea if this is a regression and needs to fixed in 2.3.15 onwards? Or there is another way of using `DefaultActionValidatorManager.getValidators()` starting 2.3.15? How to get around this problem in 2.3.16?

Comment: Similar issue was reported for 2.3.4 [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20262241/annotationactionvalidatormanager-caught-exception-while-loading-file-java-lang)

Comment: This is invalid issue, see details here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3850

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix still present in Struts 2.3.16, but moved to the `DefaultFileManager::fileNeedsReloading(URL fileUrl)`.

With respect to `ClassLoader::getResource(String name)` can return `null` value. See description of javadoc

> A URL object for reading the resource, or null if
>   the resource could not be found or the invoker doesn't have adequate 
>   privileges to get the resource.

Comment: Thanks. That explains. However in my case I am still getting NullPointerException for java/lang/Object-validation.xml as fileUrl is null for it. Any idea what I might be missing? Seems like I am missing some configuration.

Comment: There should be action class simple name or combined with action name. I think I'm not able to reproduce it because this is a glaring mistake and exception is a legit way to inform you about it.